# How to choose overloaded method by argument type?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I'm trying to overload my method depending on the argument type:

[FieldError](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html) extends [ObjectError](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/ObjectError.html).

```
private String getMessage(final FieldError fieldError) {
    return String.format("%s %s", fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
}

private String getMessage(final ObjectError objectError) {
    return objectError.getDefaultMessage();
}
```

Now, if I have a `List<ObjectError>` and call above method for elements of that `List`, regardless of which type (`ObjectError` or `FieldError`) the elements on the `List` are, 
**getMessage(final ObjectError objectError)** will always be called.

[image]

```
List<ObjectError> errors;
getMessage(errors.get(0));
```

Why is it behaving this way? If it's just how it works, is there any chance not using `if`'s and `instanceof`'s?

Comment: Maybe you should stay away from method overloading in the first place? Check this out: [The Hidden Dangers of Method Overloading](https://www.yegor256.com/2023/08/01/method-overloading.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Method overloading resolution is performed at compile time, when only the compile-time type is known. Therefore, the compile-time type of the parameters passed to the method call determine which of the overloaded methods is chosen.

Since you are passing elements of a `List<ObjectError>` to the method call, `String getMessage(final ObjectError objectError)` is always chosen, and the runtime type of the instances stored in that `List` doesn't make a difference.

One way to solve your problem is to move the `getMessage()` method to `ObjectError` class, and override it in the `FieldError` sub-class.

Instead of

```
getMessage(errors.get(0))
```

you'll call

```
errors.get(0).getMessage()
```

This will work, since method overriding is resolved at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`errors` is a List so `errors.get(0)` is an ObjectError.
According to this, the method taking an ObjectError is used because it is linked at compile time, not at runtime.

In order to do what you want, you should add a `getMessage()` method in your ObjectError class and override it for FieldError. And then, you really use polymorphism :

```
public class ObjectError {
  [...]
  public void getMessage() {
    return this.getDefaultMessage();
  }
  [...]
}

public class FieldError {
  [...]
  @Override
  public void getMessage() {
    return String.format("%s %s", this.getField(), this.getDefaultMessage());
  }
  [...]
}
```